# Finding probabilty using multivariate hypergeometric

Tags: probability

A box contains 3 green balls, 2 blue balls, and 4 red balls.  In a random sample of 5 balls, find the probability that both blue balls and at least 1 red ball are selected.

To find the probability that both blue balls are selected is somewhat trivial, it can be found by

$$\frac{{3\choose 0}*{2\choose 2}*{4\choose 0}}{{9\choose 2}}$$

However since I am looking for at least one red ball as well that would complicate the numerator and would change the denominator to ${9\choose 5}$ since 5 total are now being chosen without replacement

How can I find the numerator?

Answer (score 0):

Not so.  ${2\choose 2}\Big/{9\choose 2}$ is the probability of selecting 2 balls which are both of the blue balls.

That's not the same as selecting 5 balls which include both of the blue balls.

The probability of that is: $$\frac{{2\choose 2}{7\choose 3}}{9\choose 5}$$

The favoured case is: 2 blue balls and 3 non-blue balls.

---

Likewise the probability of selecting 2 blue balls and at least 1 red is:

$$\frac{{2\choose 2}\Bigg({7\choose 3}-{\Box\choose \Box}\Bigg)}{9\choose 5}$$

The favoured case is: 2 blue balls and 3 non-blue balls *which are not all green*.

Can you fill the boxes?